# get process mdoules c# with kernel.dll

Tags: c#, windows, module, kernel

I'm getting some trouble while running this:

```
    public MODULEENTRY32 getModule(String ModuleName)
    {
        MODULEENTRY32 module32;
        module32.dwSize = (uint) Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(MODULEENTRY32));
        IntPtr hSnap = CreateToolhelp32Snapshot(SnapshotFlags.TH32CS_SNAPMODULE | SnapshotFlags.TH32CS_SNAPMODULE32, (uint) process.Id);
        Module32First(hSnap, out module32);
        if (hSnap == IntPtr.Zero)
        {
            return new MODULEENTRY32();
        }
        do
        {
            if (module32.szModule.Equals(ModuleName))
            {
                CloseHandle(hSnap);
                return module32;
            }
        } while (Module32Next(hSnap, out module32));
        return new MODULEENTRY32();
    }
```

I was trying to get modules from a process but it always return 0,
I'm sure that the module name is corrent and the process id too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you have provided enough information to determine what the problem is.

If you read the [CreateToolHelp32Snapshot](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/tlhelp32/nf-tlhelp32-createtoolhelp32snapshot) documentation you should check if hSnap returned is INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE (-1).  If it is, you need to call GetLastError to determine the reason for the failure.

Possible reasons for failures are documented:

> If the specified process is the Idle process or one of the CSRSS
>   processes, this function fails and the last error code is
>   ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED because their access restrictions prevent
>   user-level code from opening them.
>
> If the specified process is a 64-bit process and the caller is a
>   32-bit process, this function fails and the last error code is
>   ERROR_PARTIAL_COPY (299).

and:

> When taking snapshots that include heaps and modules for a process
>   other than the current process, the CreateToolhelp32Snapshot function
>   can fail or return incorrect information for a variety of reasons. For
>   example, if the loader data table in the target process is corrupted
>   or not initialized, or if the module list changes during the function
>   call as a result of DLLs being loaded or unloaded, the function might
>   fail with ERROR_BAD_LENGTH or other error code. Ensure that the target
>   process was not started in a suspended state, and try calling the
>   function again. If the function fails with ERROR_BAD_LENGTH when
>   called with TH32CS_SNAPMODULE or TH32CS_SNAPMODULE32, call the
>   function again until it succeeds.